# iphone :- how can i change Animated Style change

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

i have one application with Arabic language .in this i want to show navigation animated  from  right to left.

means in Arabic language all things are in mirror view of english. so i want way how can i show this things ok ?

wright now my view is going in right side . but i want a way to for navigation in left side.

Answer (score 0):

ohhhhhhh yesssssss

finally i got answer we can do this like this ..

[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj transition:2 forceImmediate:YES];

it really nice code .

Comment: That is an undocumented private api method.

Comment: May be apple coder do this but i got this method with "try and error"

Comment: this code is working for me but i can't understand. how is working for me in xcode ?and what is doing ?